# Schengen visa expires before travel ban ends, can I ask for an extension instead of reapplying?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, netherlands

Today I got my schengen visa approved which I had applied for before the pandemic. 
I had plans to visit the Netherlands. Sadly, the Netherlands has a travel ban effective till April 19th and my visa expires on April 25th.

Let's say I am unable to utilize my visa, would I have to apply again with all the fees and everything, or can I write a letter to the embassy for an extension?

Comment: Being in the Netherlands, I do expect the travel ban to be extended or other travel restriction to be introduced. Forget travel to the Netherlands the next few or even many months.

Comment: Even setting the travel restrictions aside, I think wanting to travel for non-essential purposes right now is irresponsible.

Answer (score 39):

Right now, you must apply for a new visa, and it doesn't look like fees are refunded or waived:

> **Is a visa fee refundable?**
> Visa fees for visas that have not been used by COVID-19 cannot be refunded. A new application must be submitted.
>
> **I have not travelled to the Netherlands yet. Can the period of my already issued visa be extended?**
> The duration of issued visas of travelers who have not yet been able to travel to the Netherlands due to cancelled flights cannot be extended. A new visa application must be submitted.

https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/qas-short-stay-schengen-visa

Whether this changes in due course is something no one knows right now.

Comment: And why the downvote?  Just a hater hating?

Comment: @moo or someone from IPS or SO saying "glad to meet 'ya".